# Get closest parent element (excluding current element) using a selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the closest Parent element of an element.

Looking at [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), it seems to return the element itself if the selector matches with it:

> The closest() method traverses the Element and its parents (heading
> toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the
> provided selector string. **Will return itself** or the matching ancestor.
> If no such element exists, it returns null.

(emphasis is mine)

So, what would be the best way to get the closest Parent of an element given a selector?

**Example**

```js
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
var closestParent = el.closest('div');
console.log(closestParent);
```

```html
<div>root
  <div>level1
    <div id='foo'>level2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, `el.closest('div');` returns `el` itself, not its closest parent matching the selector `div` (level1), which is what I need.

I know that in this case I can simply do `closestParent.parentElement`, but this is just an example, and I am trying to figure out if it possible to avoid `.closest()` to return the element itself.

Comment: idea world the parent you want has a class and you use `.closest('.theClass')`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To exclude the current element, get the `closest()` relative to its [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
var closestParent = el.parentNode.closest('div');
console.log(closestParent);
```

Comment: yeah, you're right, that was easy: just using `el.parentNode.closest('div');` is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Document of Closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
Here is a DOM, it isn't about parent it's about the nearest Element so you can change your query like below but if  you need parents just use [parentEelement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

```js
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
var closestParent = el.closest('div:not(#foo)');
console.log(closestParent);
```

```html
<div>root
  <div>level1
    <div id='foo'>level2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```