# Select a div that contains a div having specific attribute value or class

Tags: css

I want to select a div that contains another div with specific class or specific attribute value. I have tried these: (but it selects the child not the parent/container)

```
div div[data-value="hi"]
div>div[data-value="hi"]
div div.any
div>div.any
```

(example) the one with attribute value:

```
<div>
<div data-value="hi">example</div>
</div>
```

(example) or the one below with class:

```
<div>
<div class="any">example</div>
</div>
```

Please do not suggest `nth-child` as their will be couple of div and div position is random as the below example:

```
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="any">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if it even possible with **only CSS**, Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531811/get-closest-parent-element-excluding-current-element-using-a-selector

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar thanks, but I want a CSS-based solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly and you want to target the PARENT should it contain a child with a given class or attribute, then you want the :has pseudo-selector. Note, that it isn't available in all browsers/versions yet but has good availability see: [Can I Use :has selector](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
   
}

div:has(div.other) {
  background: red;
}

div:has(div[data-value="hi"]) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="any">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div data-value="hi">example</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much, I also have found that myself. Yes, doesn't have support everywhere, but the majority supports it.

Answer (score 0):

just directly select its class or data-value

```css
div > .any {
  background: red;
}

div > [data-value="other"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div data-value="other">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="any">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="other">example</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guess the parent div has its own background color and some padding, so directly selecting the child, and changing the background color of it will not help.